# Classic ASP Parse XML Response with "<test/>" Text

Tags: xml, parsing, asp-classic

I have this response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response xmlns="http://xml.test.com">
  <test1>
    <result1/>
  </test1>
</response>
```

I have this code:

```vb
For Each node in objXML.selectSingleNode("/response").childNodes
  sResult = sResult & node.xml
Next
Response.Write Server.HTMLEncode(sResult)
```

But this gives me:

```xml
<test1 xmlns="http://xml.test.com"> <result1/> </test1>
```

How do I only get the following?:

```
result1
```

Comment: Do you need to loop through? If so shouldn't you be looping `For Each node in objXML.selectSingleNode("/response/test1").childNodes`? Then use `sResult = sResult & node.nodeName` to get the name of the `result1` node?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
For Each node in objXML.selectSingleNode("/response/test1/result1").InnerXml
```

Comment: Doesn't work... Object doesn't support this property or method: 'selectSingleNode(...).InnerXml'